# KeyError Issue when decoding JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am making telegram bot using python 3 on RPI and for HTTP requesting I used requests library
I wrote the code that should answer &start command:

```
import requests as rq

updateURL="https://api.telegram.org/bot925438333:AAGEr3pf3c4Fz91sL79mwJ6aGYm-Y6BM7_4/getUpdates"

while True:

   r=rq.post(url = updateURL)

   data = r.json()

   messageArray = data['result']
   lastMsgID=len(messageArray)-1
   lastMsgData = messageArray[lastMsgID]
   lastMsgSenderID = lastMsgData['message']['from']['id']
   lastMsgUsername = lastMsgData['message']['from']['username']
   lastMsgText = lastMsgData["message"]["text"]
   lastMsgChatType = lastMsgData['message']['chat']['type']

   if lastMsgChatType == "group":
        lastMsgGroupID = lastMsgData['message']['chat']['id']

   if lastMsgText == "&start":
      if lastMsgChatType == "private":
        URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot925438333:AAGEr3pf3c4Fz91sL79mwJ6aGYm-Y6BM7_4/sendMessage"

        chatText="Witamy w KozelBot"
        chatID=lastMsgSenderID
        Params={"chat_id":chatID,"text":chatText}

        rs = rq.get(url = URL, params = Params)

      if lastMsgChatType == "group":
        URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot925438333:AAGEr3pf3c4Fz91sL79mwJ6aGYm-Y6BM7_4/sendMessage"

        chatText="Witamy w KozelBot"
        chatID=lastMsgGroupID
        Params={"chat_id":chatID,"text":chatText}

        rs = rq.get(url = URL, params = Params)
```

but the code outputs an error:

> File "/home/pi/telegramResponse.py", line 16, in 
>       lastMsgText = lastMsgData["message"]["text"]
>   KeyError: 'text'

I don't know how to solve this problem because this fragment is working fine in my other scripts!
Please help!

Comment: I would suggest you print `lastMsgData`. You will see undoubtedly what the source of the problem is.

Comment: It means lastMsgData["message"] does not contain field 'text'.

Comment: ```KeyError``` occurs when you try to access key which is not in the dictionary, ```astMsgData["message"]["text"] ``` ```text``` key is not available in dict. So avoid using this this way to access dictionary data, instead use ```.get()``` method on dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was simple!
Last message that program finds doesn't contain any text because it was new user notification. KeyError just occured because last message doesn't have `['text']` parameter.